# SoundJS - registering 4 sounds in an audiosprite

Tags: javascript, soundjs

I'm loading a SoundJS 1.0 audiosprite with preloadJS 1.0. The audiosprite is split into 4 sounds which I'm calling a,b,c and d. (Elsewhere in the code it randomizes which of the 4 sounds to play.)

Here's the basic loading and declaration code:

```
 var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
 createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
 queue.addEventListener("complete",handleComplete);

 //load audiosprite and define start/duration times with variables.
 queue.loadFile({src:path,data:{
     audioSprite:[
     {id:sound+"a", startTime:aStart, duration: aDur},
     {id:sound+"b", startTime:bStart, duration: bDur},
     {id:sound+"c", startTime:cStart, duration: cDur},
     {id:sound+"d", startTime:dStart, duration: dDur},
     ]
     }});

 //register the 4 audioSprite sounds as individual sound instances
    myAudio[sound+"a"] = createjs.Sound.createInstance(sound+"a");
    myAudio[sound+"b"] = createjs.Sound.createInstance(sound+"b");
    myAudio[sound+"c"] = createjs.Sound.createInstance(sound+"c");
    myAudio[sound+"d"] = createjs.Sound.createInstance(sound+"d");
```

When I load the sound I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

If I comment out the last 3 lines and just create 1 instance (eg. sound+"a"), the sound loads and I get no error, but obviously I only get 1 of the 4 parts.

I feel like the problem is it doesn't like me calling createInstance back to back like this. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loadManifest for multiple files; loadFile only loads a single file.

```
 queue.loadManifest({src:path,data:{
 audioSprite:[
 {id:sound+"a", startTime:aStart, duration: aDur},
 {id:sound+"b", startTime:bStart, duration: bDur},
 {id:sound+"c", startTime:cStart, duration: cDur},
 {id:sound+"d", startTime:dStart, duration: dDur},
 ]
 }});
```

Edit - the handlePreloadComplete function from line 286 looks a bit suspect and may be a bug https://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/files/soundjs_AbstractPlugin.js.html

```
p._handlePreloadComplete = function (event) {
    var src = event.target.getItem().src;
    this._audioSources[src] = event.result;
    for (var i = 0, l = this._soundInstances[src].length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = this._soundInstances[src][i];
        item.playbackResource = this._audioSources[src];
        // ToDo consider adding play call here if playstate == playfailed
        this._soundInstances[src] = null;
    }
};
```

Iterating over the length of this._soundInstances[src], but then setting it to null on the first iteration will give the error you mention.

Perhaps it should be

```
this._soundInstances[src][i] = null;
```

Comment: I wondered about that as well, but it's an audio sprite, so technically one file. I got it working in one part of the code by moving the registering of the sounds into the handleComplete function. However, in another part it doesn't seem to be working yet. It all works with the older NEXT version of SoundJS, just not the 1.0 version.

Comment: I see, looks like this could be a bug - see above edit.

Comment: Thanks, the edit seemed to help but then it gets stuck on the playbackResource line giving me the familiar "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null". For now, I'm going back to the older Next version of SoundJS that was all working properly.